# Read printer status after writing test string

Tags: c#, .net, hardware, thermal-printer, epson

I'm trying to write a string to a serial port, then send a command to tell the printer to return it's status in real time, if OK then send the next string.

I know how to create the form, create a serial port and write my string:

```
serialPort.Write("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN\n");

// send command to read status

// if status = 4, warn user & close port, if not...

// send next string

serialPort.Write("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN\n");
```

Where I'm having trouble is sending & receiving the real time status.
The command is:

```
Transmit real-time status
ASCII DLE EOTn [a]
Hex 10 04 n [a]
Decimal 16 4 n [a]

TM-T90, TM-T88IV, TM-U220 : 1 ≤ n ≤ 4, n = 7

TM-L90: 1 ≤ n ≤ 4, n = 8, a = 3 (when n = 8) (TM-L90 with Peeler)

1 ≤ n ≤ 4 (TM-L90 without Peeler)

n a Function
1 -- Transmit printer status
2 -- Transmit offline status
3 -- Transmit error status
4 -- Transmit roll paper sensor status
7 1 Transmit ink status A
2 Transmit ink status B
8 3 Transmit peeler status
```

All I care about is where n = 4 (Transmit roll paper sensor status)

If n returns 4, stop and close port with message to user that paper is low.

I will be using the same program for a 4 printers listed, like I said all I care about is if the status changes from 0 to 4.

I hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: You don't say what problem you're experiencing. You don't say what library you're using. Looks like from the tag it's some Epson printers?

Comment: I believe I would need to run the printer return codes in a separate thread. Basically what I am trying to do is send a line of code "ABCDEFG....", after the printer prints the line, execute the Status checker code reading the status code. Of it is "00" or "03" continue, if not "00" or "03" then stop printing and display the error code as a message.